# C++ Libssh -sever/client file transfer over the lan example

Tags: c++, lan, libssh2, libssh

Newbie here basically I'm trying to build a sever/client file transfer application that transfers files and folders over the lan. Does any one have any sample application that I can look into that uses C++? Libssh examples are all in C which I already looked into. And what's the deal with libssh and libssh2?

Comment: Examples are available on the [libssh2 website](https://www.libssh2.org/examples/)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think somebody will write the code for you. You have to get your hands dirty :)